# Haskell - get n number of lists from a list of lists

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

Hey guys so I'm trying and get the n number of lists from a list of lists. I was wondering if there is a method in haskell that works similar to the "take" and "drop" method but instead if would work in my situation. For example:

`Input = [ [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9,1,2], [3,4,5,6] ]`

I want to be able to take the first 3 elements from this list of lists and end up with something like this:

`Output = [ [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,1,2,3]]`

I also want to be able to drop the first 3 elements from this list of lists and end up with something like this:

`Output = [[4,5,6,7], [8,9,1,2], [3,4,5,6]]`

Is it possible to do something like this in haskell.? Can anyone point me into the right direction on how to tackle this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`take` and `drop` do exactly that. They work the same for all element types, even if the element type is a list type.

```
Prelude> take 3 [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20]]
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
Prelude> drop 3 [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20]]
[[13,14,15,16],[17,18,19,20]]
```

Comment: And don't forget about `splitAt`!